# Tumblr: how to make div wrap around photo?

Tags: html, css, image

[Here](http://dimashishkov.tumblr.com/)'s the web-page.

How can I make `div` wrap around image tightly? Now it sticks at the bottom of the image for 4px (see red line, I gave a div red background).

I can't understand where those 4px come from and how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the image `vertical-align: bottom` or give the containing div `line-height: 0`.

This is due to the fact the image is set to `inline-block` and the way `inline` elements are rendered. You could also make the image a block level element.

Your choice.

Comment: @Dima No problem. http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/remove-space-below-images-and-inline-block-elements.html explains why this happens. It's to accomodate font descenders.

Comment: Thanks. I will certainly read this article. Have to make my mind separate inline and block elements and how they behave.