# Tumblr - wrapping text around image

Tags: word-wrap

The blog: [takekey.tumblr](http://takekey.tumblr.com/)

I'd like the text beneath the 'Rick Hanson' image to run down it's right-hand side with a margin of about 8px.

I found another answer on here, but the solutions are not working for me.

[Other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990920/tumblr-how-to-make-div-wrap-around-photo)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I didn't realise I could get to the html of the post itself.

I just needed to add: `img style="float: left; padding: 0px 14px 0px 0px;"` before the `src`